# Export all guest customers

Tags: orders, customer, export

I would like to give my client, who is running a Magento Store, the possibility, in the backend, to export the list of all guest customers who made orders.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a module that adds the `customer_is_guest` column to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table.  Once this is done the value from `sales_flat_order` will automatically copy over when orders are created (you'll have to update all the old ones though).

Next you need to add a `Customer Is Guest` column to the grid in **Sales > Orders**.  This can be done by extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareColumns()` and adding

```
$this->addColumn('customer_is_guest', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Is Guest'),
    'index' => 'customer_is_guest',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options' => array(
        0 => Mage::helper('sales')->__('No'),
        1 => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Yes')
    ),
));
```

Now you'll be able to filter the grid by guest checkouts.  Then simply use the built in <kbd>Export</kbd> button at the top of the page to get the results in CSV or XML format.

Comment: this will help -: https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/add-column-to-magento-sales-order-grid-best-practice-way.html

Answer (score 0):

You should create a module with something like this:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFiter('customer_is_guest',1);

foreach($orderCollection as $order){
    //info if guest is here, export it anyway you want
    $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname(); 
}
```

Comment: You have a Typo in your code: addFieldToFiter, should be addFieldToFilter